# Platform builder and compiling options and flags

Tags: windows-ce, arm, compilation, platform-builder

I'm new to platform builder, this might be obvious..

I'm working on wince6.0.

I've looked everywhere, didn't find how to add flags to the compilation of the image.
I've noticed there are many flags which are specific to ARM:

http://207.46.16.248/en-us/library/ee479941%28WinEmbedded.60%29.aspx

/QRArch

/QRimplicit-import-

/QRinterwork-return

/QRxscale

/QRxscalesched

/QRthumb

How do I add them to the build and which ones take parameters (and what are they)? 
Are there any general flags too? what are they?

Thank you

Comment: Btw, I'm using VS2005 if it matters

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you need to do two things:

- Go to project properties
- Add environment variable named "cl" with value such as the following or a subset of them:

  /QRArch

  /QRimplicit-import-

  /QRinterwork-return

  /QRxscale

  /QRxscalesched

  /QRthumb

Afterwards, you edit the sources.cmn located in the BSP folder, adding:

```
CDEFINES=$(CDEFINES) <the flags you picked above>
```

For example if I wanted to use `/QRArch4` and `/QRimplicit-import-`
The cl variable value would be `/QRArch4` `/QRimplicit-import-`

and the line added to the sources is:

```
 CDEFINES=$(CDEFINES) /QRArch4 /QRimplicit-import-
```